# Where does googolplum lie in the fast growing hierarchy?

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

Here :

https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/3-2/andre_joyce

Saibian presents the largest number coined by Andre Joyce, googolplum.

It should lie at the $f_{\omega+2}$-level in the fast growing hierarchy,
but where exactly ?

In other words :

> Between which tight bounds does googolplum lie ? Is it really at level $f_{\omega+2}$ ?
>
> If yes, what is the smallest number $n$, such that $f_{\omega+2}(n)$ is bigger than googolplum ?

The construction of googolplum works as follows :

Start with $10**100$, where $**$ stands for exponentiation. This is step $1$.
In step $2$, we have $10**\cdot\cdot\cdot**10\ $ with $10**100=googol$ stars. In step $3$, we have $10**\cdot\cdot\cdot**10\ $ with as many stars as given by the number in step $2$. Continue in this manner until step

$$(10^{100})\uparrow^{3^{27}-2} (10^{100})$$ is reached.

Here :

https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/appendix/a/numbers2

Saibian gives bounds for googolplum. It should be less than $G(G(2))$.

I did not get the meaning of the stars, so I have difficulties to determine the size of the number. I think it has something to do with up-arrow-notation but then I do not understand why $**$ stands for exponentiation.

Comment: Using $**$ for exponentiation comes from computer languages such as FORTRAN.  We would deprecate it in favor of ^ For numbers like this, you want powers of uparrow as you have done.

Comment: What would $6$ stars mean for example ?

Comment: I haven't seen the use of more than $2$ stars.  I didn't find it in the article you linked to. Whoever uses it should define it.  Maybe it is three uparrows, with two stars converting to one uparrow.

Comment: That is also my guess.

Comment: Hmm, as large ever that googol-extensions may occur - it seems that an alternating series  *1-10+10^^2-10^^3+10^^4+...-...googol+10^googol - ...+ ...*  has a decent, small, reasonable value somewhere near 0.26 using a divergent-series-summation method... :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I do not remeber the sequence with the value $-\frac{1}{12}$ clearly diverging and having only positive elements. This was often posted here because apparently it is used in physics ...

Comment: Peter, I didn't mean the zeta-series. I thought you would easily recognize the alternating ***tetration-series*** - and besides a proposed result of mine there does of course not exist any estimation of this series with such radically growing terms...

Comment: Saibian [approximates](https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/3-2/andre_joyce) it as $\{10,\{10,10,3^{27}\},1,2\}$. I will write a longer answer soon.

Comment: The binary hyperoperations are sometimes denoted by choosing to repeat the symbol for an operation that precedes $\uparrow$, i.e. repeating $*$ or $+$. Thus, $$(+,*,\uparrow,\uparrow\uparrow,\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow,...)= (+,\ *,\ **,\ ***,\ ****,\ ...)=(+, ++, +++, ++++, +++++, ...).$$ So $n$ "$\uparrow$"s means the same as $n+1$ "$*$"s or $n+2$ "$+$"s. The "$*$" version is described in the OP's first linked paper, in the section on the Ackermann function.

Comment: (cont'd) Therefore, the number of steps you describe is $(10^{100})\uparrow^{3^{27}-2} (10^{100})  = (10^{100}){*}^{3^{27}-1} (10^{100})$. (That is, $3^{27}-1$ is the number of *stars*, so the number of uparrows is one less than that.)

Comment: @RossMillikan : It's about 1/6th of the way in: "* denotes multiplication [,] ** denotes ^ [exponentiation,] *** denotes ^^ [tetration, and so on]".  (Parts in square brackets added by me.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism

Comment: A googolplum sounds yummy.  :P

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Was that evaluated using Euler's summation method?

Comment: @CountIblis Why drop out on the chance to do some more math?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm all in favor of doing more math. One missed opportunity is to get to a proper ultafinitistic foundation of calculus, I explain a bit about that [in this YouTube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiZP5sakM9M&lc=z12euprrfobgexcjm04cdjmglx3btz0yxc4).

Comment: Haha, okay, as long as you have your reasons :-) @CountIblis

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : No, that summation was tried using a matrix-method. I must admit I've really been novice in number theory, learning tetration and summation on my own... My first attempt to such series has been this: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/10_4_Powertower_article.pdf and I didn't know that much more has to be done. I involved in a discussion in sci math.research: 
http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/IterationSeriesSummation_1.htm and arrived at this estimated graph: 
http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/IterationSeriesSummation_1-Dateien/image003.jpg .Not (yet!) waterproof

Comment: (... contd...) I was such a novice that I even did not know the name "Carlemanmatrix" for what I'd (re) discovered (by really long and tidy analyses!), and also did not know the name "Neumann-series" (for matrices). But reading it today is again real fun... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining $$f(x):=10\uparrow^{x-1}100,$$ we have $$\mathrm{googolplum} =f^N(2) ,$$ where  $$N = (10^{100})\uparrow^{3^{27}-2} (10^{100}).$$

Here's a proof (sketch) that

> $$f_{\omega+2}(2) < \mathrm{googolplum} < f_{\omega+2}(3)\tag{*}. $$

For the inequality on the left in $(*)$:
$$f_{\omega+2}(2) = f_{\omega+1}^2(2) =  f_{\omega+1}(a) = f_\omega^a(a) < (f^2)^\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}-1}\right\rfloor f^2(2) \le f^N(2)
$$
where $a=f_{\omega+1}(2)=f_\omega^2(2)=f_\omega f_2(2)=f_8(8) \lt \left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}-1}\right\rfloor \lt f^2(2)$, and we've used the following fact: 
$$f_\omega(n) < f^2(n) \text{ for all } n\ge 2\tag{1}.$$

For the inequality on the right in $(*)$:
$$f_{\omega+2}(3) = f_{\omega+1}^3(3)=f_{\omega+1}(b) = f_\omega^b(b) \ge (f_\omega^2)^{\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\right\rfloor}(b) > f^N(2)
$$
where $b = f_{\omega+1}f_\omega^3(3)\gg 2N $, and we've used the following fact: $$f_\omega^2(n)>f(n) \text{ for all } n\ge 2\tag{2}.$$
QED

---

**NB**: Defining the "Graham's number functions"$$ g(x):= 3\uparrow^x 3,\text{ and } G(n):= g^n(4)$$ (so Graham's number is $G(64)$), the claim that $$\text{googolplum }<G^2(2)$$ can be proved correct as follows:

First, consider the following function (which is everywhere larger than googolplum's $f(x)$):
$$\phi(x):= (10^{100})\uparrow^{x-1}(10^{100}) > f(x)$$
and note that
$$\begin{align} 3\uparrow^x 3 &= 3\uparrow^{x-1}3\uparrow^{x-1}3 \\
&\ge 3\uparrow^{x-1}(3\uparrow^3 3),\quad x\ge4\\
&>(3\uparrow^{x-1}3)\uparrow^{x-1}(3\uparrow^3 3 - 3),\quad x\ge4\quad\text{(by Saibian's theorem)}\\
&>(3\uparrow^3 3)\uparrow^{x-1}(3\uparrow^3 3 - 3),\quad x\ge4\\
&>(10^{100})\uparrow^{x-1}(10^{100}),\quad x\ge4\\
\therefore\ g(x)&>\phi(x)>f(x),\quad x\ge4.\\
\end{align}
$$
and also that
$$N = (10^{100})\uparrow^{3^{27}-2} (10^{100}) < (10^{100})\uparrow^{10^{100}-1} (10^{100}) = \phi(10^{100}) < g(10^{100}) < g(3\uparrow^4 3)
$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\text{googolplum } &:= f^N(2)<\phi^N(4)< g^N(4) < g^{g(3\uparrow^4 3)}(4)=g^{g(g(4))}(4)=G(g(g(4)))=G(G(2)).
\end{align}
$$
QED

(ref: [Saibian's theorem](http://vixra.org/pdf/1405.0284v1.pdf) [see T1])

Comment: Nice, and it coincides with the fact that $f_{\omega+2}(3)\approx 3\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 3$, and the conway chain already exceeds googolplum.

Comment: What about my claim that $$googolplum<G(G(2))$$, where $G(n)$ is the Graham-function ?

Comment: @Peter -  Your claim is correct. I've added a proof.

Comment: @Peter - BTW, your post still needs to have the uparrow-count ${3^{27}-1}$ corrected. It should be ${3^{27}-2}$, as explained in my earlier comment.

Comment: So, we have $G(G(1))<googolplum<G(G(2))$ (The lower bound is mentioned in my second link)

Comment: @Deedlit If you want, you can search for even tighther bounds for googolplum :)

Answer (score 3):

I will adopt r.e.s.'s terminology

$$N = (10^{100}) \uparrow^{3^{27}-2} (10^{100})$$

and

$$f(n) = 10\uparrow^{n-1} 100$$

so that

$$\text{googolplum} = f^N(2).$$

We will prove

$$f_{\omega+1}(N-2) < \text{googolplum} < f_{\omega+1}(N-1)$$

To prove this we will use (without proof) the inequalities

$$2 \uparrow^{n-1}(n+1) \le f_\omega(n) < 2 \uparrow^{n-1}(2n) < 2 \uparrow^{n-1}(2 \uparrow^{n-1} 4) = 2\uparrow^n 4$$

We prove the right inequality by proving $f_{\omega}^i(N-1) > f^{i+1}(2)$ by induction.

Base case: $N-1 > f(2) = 10^{100}$.

Inductive step: If $f_{\omega}^i(N-1) > f^{i+1}(2)$, then 
$$f_{\omega}^{i+1}(N-1) = f_{\omega}(f_\omega^i(N-1)) > f_\omega(f^{i+1}(2)) > 2 \uparrow^{f^{i+1}(2)-1}(f^{i+1}(2)+1) > (2\uparrow^{f^{i+1}(2)-1} 3)\uparrow^{f^{i+1}(2)-1}(f^{i+1}(2) - 2) \lbrace \text{by Saibian's Theorem}\rbrace > 10\uparrow^{f^{i+1}(2)-1}100 = f^{i+2}(2)$$ QED

Substituting $i = N-1$ produces the right inequality.

For the left inequality, we prove $f_{\omega}^i(N-2) < f^{i+2}(2)$ also by induction.

Base case: $N-2 < f(f(2)) = 10 \uparrow^{10^{100}-1} 100$.

Inductive step: If $f_{\omega}^i(N-2) < f^{i+2}(2)$, then

$$f_{\omega}^{i+1}(N-2) = f_\omega(f_{\omega}^{i+1}(N-2)) \le f_{\omega}(f^{i+2}(2)-1) < 2\uparrow^{f^{i+2}(2)-1} 4 < 10 \uparrow^{f^{i+2}(2)-1} 100 = f(f^{i+2}(2)) = f^{i+3}(2)$$
QED

and we get the left inequality by substituting $i = N-2$.

If you wish to get rid of Knuth arrows entirely, observe that

$$f_\omega(3^{27}-1) < 2\uparrow^{3^{27}-2}(2 \cdot 3^{27})< N-2 < N-1 < 2\uparrow^{3^{27}-1}(3^{27}+1) < f_\omega(3^{27})$$

so that

$$f_{\omega+1}(f_\omega(3^{27}-1)) < \text{googolplum} < f_{\omega+1}(f_\omega(3^{27}))$$