# How big are $f_3(3)$ and $f_4(4)$ in the fast growing hierarchy?

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

I read some articles about the fast growing hierarchy (and saw some vids), and I wonder how to calculate:

1. $f_3(3)$
2. And especially $f_4(4)$

I know that there are huge numbers, but I wonder if someone here can give me estimate how big are those huge numbers...
i.e. for example - how many digits there are at each one of them.

Comment: Are you simply not understanding the definition of these functions? Because the definition describes how you would "calculate" it.

Comment: (One thing worth noting is that there are _multiple_ fast-growing hierarchies, all broadly similar but each generally tailored to specific needs of the construction.)

Comment: I edit the question...

Comment: According to a Numberphile video f3(3) is a number with 121 million digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can directly compute $f_3(3)$ using the definition to get

\begin{align}f_3(3)&=f_2(f_2(f_2(3)))\\&=f_2(f_2(24))\\&=f_2(402653184)\\&=402653184\times2^{402653184}\end{align}

Taking the base 10 log of this gives

\begin{align}\log_{10}(402653184\times2^{402653184})&=\log_{10}(402653184)+402653184\log_{10}(2)\\&\simeq121210694\end{align}

which is the amount of digits this has.

$f_4(4)$ cannot be worked out similarly. The closest representable expression for the amount of digits $f_4(4)$ has is $f_4(4)$. A rough lower bound can be obtained by expanding it out and using $f_3(n)>2^n\uparrow\uparrow n\ge16\uparrow\uparrow n$ for $n\ge4$.

\begin{align}f_4(4)&=f_3(f_3(f_3(f_3(4))))\\&>16\uparrow\uparrow(16\uparrow\uparrow(16\uparrow\uparrow(16\uparrow\uparrow4)))\\&>4\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow5\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the meaning of *calculate*.

If you want a decimal string representation, then it is not really possible, as the number of bits required to store that string would very soon exceed the number of atoms in the universe.

On the other hand, you can prove various properties of these numbers. For example, what are the last three digits of $f_4(4)$? How does it compare to other big numbers, such as those given by Knuth's up-arrow notations? etc.

It is the same philosophy as what we mean by "calculating $\pi$" or "calculating $\sqrt 2$". You are never able to represent its decimal expansion with finite amount of information, but this doesn't stop you from proving results such as $\frac 1 {1^2} + \frac 1 {2^2} + \cdots = \frac {\pi^2} 6$.

Comment: Yes, I mean, if you can give me some "facts" about the $f_3(3)$ for example it will help me a lot (like what you wrote at the middle paragraph...:-)

Comment: Have you checked the [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy)? Some informations are provided there.

Comment: Yes, but I'm get confused when I try to calculate something like $f_3(3)$ and this is why I asked the question here...

Comment: See the section *Approximate growth rates in comparison to other googological notations* for a list of properties of these functions. The majority of these results are definitely not proved by "calculating" the numbers. You may try to prove some of them to get a feeling of how to deal with these numbers.

Comment: I saw it, but according to wikipedia $f_3(3)\approx 2\uparrow \uparrow 3$, but according to the video it's something like $10^{121}$ - so which one is correct?

Comment: Wiki gives an inequality, not that they are the same size.

Comment: @CS1 Indeed those bounds on Wikipedia are fairly loose. Direct calculations will give you that $f_3(3)=402653184\times2^{402653184}$, which, when converted to base 10 will give you roughly $6.895\mathrm E121210694$. For tighter bounds you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348925) and [here](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/User_blog:Simply_Beautiful_Art/Even_tighter_bounds_on_f_3_in_the_fast_growing_hierarchy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SimplyBeautifulArt! This is what I look for ;-)  $f_3(3)=402653184\times2^{402653184}$ it's not at base of 10? And the value of $f_4(4)$ is known? (like the form you gave me $f_3(3)$? Thank you!

Comment: @CS1 The question still boils down to what you exactly mean by that, as the comments and this answer have been saying. What is the issue with directly using the definition?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt - if it will make it more clear I'm trying to understand how mnay digits there are at each one... :-)

Comment: I edit the question that now I hope it's much more clear... @SimplyBeautifulArt